# Call to a member function fill() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel-4

Trying to add information to an empty `profile` and redirect back.

```
$user = User::whereUsername($username)->firstOrFail(); // Selects correct user

$input = Input::all(); // a dd($input) at this point confirms input present

$this->profileForm->validate($input); // Passes

$user->profile->fill($input)->save();

return Redirect::route('profile.edit', $user->username);
```

If `$user->profile` is `null` then this gives the error: `Call to a member function fill() on a non-object`. I tried to remedy this with:

```
$user = User::whereUsername($username)->firstOrFail(); // Selects correct user

$input = Input::all(); // a dd($input) at this point confirms input present

$this->profileForm->validate($input); // Passes

if ($user->profile == null)
{
    $user->profile = new Profile;
}

$user->profile->fill($input)->save();

return Redirect::route('profile.edit', $user->username);
```

But in this case it is redirected without adding the profile details (`$user->profile` is still `null` at this point).

If $user->profile already has information then this problem does not occur and the code works fine.

Comment: Do you initialize new Profile before calling `fill()` ?

Comment: Yes, the if clause is added before `fill()`. I've edited the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
if (count($user->profile))
{   
    $user->profile->fill($input)->save();
}
else
{
    $profile = Profile::create($input);

    $user->profile()->save($profile);
}
```

Comment: Interesting, that gives me a database error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'profile' in 'field list' (SQL: update users set updated_at = 2014-09-25 09:05:01, profile = {"firstname":"sdf","lastname":"sd"} where id = 12)`

Comment: Ok, edited my answer to reflect the correct saving of a related model.