# How to update table with multiple entries. Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, one-to-many

UPDATED. I have one form that adds data to two different tables (Articles & Deals). An Article has many deals. A deal has one Article. There are multiple *deals* with different *dealname*s that the user inputs on the create and edit form. I can create an Article with many Deals fine, and I can populate the edit form with the data from the Deals table, *but* when I update my 'deals' table using the Articles Controller it just updates every 'dealname' with the last dealname that is inputted.  I only need to update the 'dealname' column as all other columns will stay the same. If I remove the dealname/deals part of the form I can update fine.

How can I update the deals table correctly? I know I have to change something in the update function of my Articles Controller.

I'm using Laravel 5.

The Articles Table has: id, title, image, description, address. The Deals table has: id, dealname, article_id, dayID.

**Articles Controller- Update**

```
     public function update(ArticleRequest $request, $id)
        {
         $article = Article::find($id);
          if( $request->hasFile('image') ){
                // photo saving stuff.
           }
        $article->fill($request->input())->save();
//Get IDs of deals to be updated.
        $dealID = Deal::all()->lists('dealname', 'id');
        $dealID = $dealID->toArray();
        $dealID = array_keys($dealID);

        $deals = $request->input('dealname');

    foreach($deals as $deal) {
             Deal::whereIn('id', $dealID)->update(['dealname' => $deal]);

            }   
            return redirect('/');
        }
```

**Form**

```
{!! Form::model($article, ['route' => ['articleUpdate_path', $article->id], 'files' => true, 'method' => 'PATCH']) !!}

    {!! Form::label('title','TITLE') !!}
    {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    {!! $errors->first('title','<p class="error">:message</p>')!!}

    {!! Form::label('image','PHOTO') !!}
    {!! Form::file('image', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

    {!! Form::label('description','DESCRIPTION') !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

@foreach ($article->deals as $deal)

    @if($deal->dayID == '1' )
     {!! Form::label('dealname','Monday') !!}
     {!! Form::text('dealname[]', $deal->dealname, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => '1']) !!}
     @endif

    @if($deal->dayID == '2' )
     {!! Form::label('dealname','Tuesday') !!}
     {!! Form::text('dealname[]', $deal->dealname, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => '2']) !!}
    @endif
    @if($deal->dayID == '3' )
      {!! Form::label('dealname','Wednesday') !!}
      {!! Form::text('dealname[]', $deal->dealname, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => '3']) !!}
    @endif
@endforeach

    {!! Form::label('address','ADDRESS') !!}
    {!! Form::text('address', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Articles Controller -Store**

```
    public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
    {
        $image_name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $request->file('image')->move(base_path().'/public/images', $image_name);
        $article = ($request->except(['image']));
        $article['image'] = $image_name; 

        $article = Article::create($article);

// GET INPUT
        $deals = $request->input('dealname');

// GET ID OF ARTICLE
        $articleID = $article->id;
// N is the day id that increments
        $n = 1;
        foreach($deals as $deal) {

           Deal::create(['dealname' => $deal, 'article_id' => $articleID, 'dayID' => $n++]);

        }   

       return redirect()->route('articles_path');

    }
```

**ARTICLE MODEL**

```
class Article extends Model
{
    public function deals()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Deal');
    }  
protected $fillable = array('title', 'photo', 'description', 'address'); 
}
```

**DEAL MODEL**

```
class Deal extends Model
{
    public function article()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Article')->withTimestamps();
    }
    protected $fillable = array('dealname', 'article_id', 'dayID'); 
}
```

Comment: Not seen `fill()` used before, it doesn't seem to be documented either. Also, to get the input as an array you can use `$request->all();`. Does `$request->input()` even contain any data? . Does `$article->update($request->all())` not work?

Comment: Thanks. fill() worked for updating Article before I added the deal stuff. Article and Deal are different tables so I think I need to update them differently?  Here's an example of fill()http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034176/call-to-a-member-function-fill-on-a-non-object

Comment: `update()` is basically an alias for `fill()->save()` https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1416

Comment: This has not much to do with the question, but you shouldn't be using the `->withTimestamps()` method on a belongsTo relationship, it is for a `belongsToMany` relationship... However, I can't understand very well the question :/

Comment: Thanks @El_Matella I've fixed that. I've also clarified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not sure to fully understand your question, but would something like that could be useful in your case:

```
public function update(ArticleRequest $request, $id) {
    $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
    if( $request->hasFile('image') ){
        // photo saving stuff.
    }
    $article->update($request->all());
    $article->deals->where('dayID',1)->first()->dealname = $request->input('dealname')[0];
    $article->deals->where('dayID',1)->first()->save();
    $article->deals->where('dayID',2)->first()->dealname = $request->input('dealname')[1];
    $article->deals->where('dayID',2)->first()->save();
    $article->deals->where('dayID',3)->first()->dealname = $request->input('dealname')[2];
    $article->deals->where('dayID',3)->first()->save();
}
```

Are they only those 3 dayIds you are using in your form?

**EDIT:** 
You could also try with a `for` loop. This is untested code, so you might want to optimize it :)

```
public function update(ArticleRequest $request, $id) {
    $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
    if( $request->hasFile('image') ){
        // photo saving stuff.
    }
    $article->update($request->all());
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($request->input('dealname')); $i++) {
        $article->deals->where('dayID',($i + 1))->first()->dealname = $request->input('dealname')[$i];
        $article->deals->where('dayID',($i + 1))->first()->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: woah. that totally works! I have all days of the week (7dayids). I assume there's a way to do this with a foreach right?

Comment: Any idea why this wouldn't work when I deploy to server? I get 'Creating default object from empty value' error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35833903/error-when-updating-database-after-deploying-to-server-laravel-5